# Why is my component from a previous page re-rendering after changing pages using router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

When I link from one page to another, a component from the previous page remains on the page after changing to the new page. I start at the landing page and change to the results page using this.props.history.push('/results'). On the results page, another component named BarChart renders. After it is done rendering, I click a link that takes me back to the landing page using . After returning to the landing page, the landing page component renders but the BarChart also remains on the page

I have tried all the solutions that I could find such as wrapping my App with BrowserRouter, Switch, wrapping my exported components using withRouter and more.

App.js:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  ...
}

const App = () =>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={routes.RESULTS} component={() => <ResultsPage />} />
      <Route exact path={routes.LANDING} component={() => <LandingPage />} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>

export default App;
```

My 3 components:

landing.js:

```
class LandingPage extends Component {

  ...

  //how I handle switching to results page/component:
  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    get_data(this.state.search);
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push("/results");
  }

...

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(LandingPage);
```

results.js:

```
import BarChart from './barchart';

class ResultsPage extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    ...

    //routes.LANDING = '/'


    return (
      <div>
      <Link to={routes.LANDING}>Back to landing page</Link>
      <BarChart width={width} height={height}/>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(ResultsPage);
```

barchart.js:

```
class BarChart extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.drawChart = this.drawChart.bind(this);
  }

  drawChart() {

    ...

  }

  render() {

    this.drawChart();
    return (
        <div>
        <svg></svg>
        </div>
        );
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.dataState.data,

});

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(BarChart);
```

Comment: Why do you have two times the same path? `path={routes.RESULTS}`

Comment: Oh, that was a mistake I forgot to remove. I still have the same problem nevertheless. Corrected.

Comment: What are the values of `routes.RESULTS` and `routes.LANDING`

Comment: routes.RESULTS = '/results'
routes.LANDING = '/'

Comment: I am not sure about this, but did you try passing the component straight instead of a function? Like `component={ResultsPage}`

Comment: Yes, I have tried this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to switch the order of your routes :)

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={() => <LandingPage />} />
  <Route exact path="/results" component={() => <ResultsPage />} />
</Switch>
```

"every  that matches the location renders inclusively" - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: That unfortunately did not fix my problem.

Comment: Do you have a codesandbox I can help troubleshoot with?